# Why is a package not available on NuGet?

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget, package, xceed

I see from [Codeplex](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) that Xceed's Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition v2.4.0 has just been released.

My C# project references the NuGet package of the Toolkit, but is not reporting the update (I'm still using v2.3.0).

Can someone enlighten me as to the process of how the update will be available through NuGet?

Comment: There is nothing wrong on your side, they haven't pushed the new version to nuget. I'm afraid you just have to wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to contact the maintainer of [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/) in order to determine that. In this case, Xceed. He/they has to push it into the NuGet repository. Then you can update to the latest version.

Although if I were you, I'd give it a day or two before contacting. If it was only released a short time ago, then you should be patient and wait for him/they to have the time to package and test the package. Or since the library is open source, you could offer to assist with creating packages or creating a script to automate that process.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I thought that was the case, but wasn't sure exactly how it worked.

Comment: @Peter if you don't understand how NuGet repositories work, [set one up](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Hosting-Your-Own-NuGet-Feeds)! It's quite simple, and is a great thing to use for libraries that you create internally and use on multiple projects. And if you create something really useful, you can push it into the official NuGet feed and share your work with others.